# Android get extra in receiver after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarm, reboot

I'm developing an application which remind user. It's working well but when i set it and reboot device returns null on notification. I think the problem is on broadcast receiver. Because can't get any string from intent extra.

-- in activity --

```
private void setAlarm() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    String data = descripton.getText().toString();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("notify_message", data);
    myIntent.putExtras(b);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

-- manifest --

```
 <receiver  android:name=".ekstra.AlarmReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

-- broadcastreceiver --

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        //Afret reboot test1 and test2 is null
        String test1 = extras.getString("notify_message");
        String test2 = intent.getStringExtra("notify_message");
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, RemindingService.class);
        newIntent.putExtra("messaage", message);
        context.startService(newIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Test", "error " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: After a reboot, you are not receiving those broadcasts anymore, because your `AlarmManager` schedule will be wiped out.

Comment: no I can receive broadcast and get notification but after reboot it's always null value thats my problem

Comment: Then somewhere you are rescheduling your alarms, and somewhere in there you are forgetting to set your extras. I repeat: your `AlarmManager` schedule will be wiped out on a reboot.

Comment: thank a lot it my fault :) you are right

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above you will not receive broadcasts after reboot. 
But here if you are calling same AlarmReceiver when Boot Completes, which is broadcast by System So there , following will return null

```
String test1 = extras.getString("notify_message");//test1 is null
```

OR

```
String test2 = intent.getStringExtra("notify_message");//test2 is null
```

(both calls are equivalent )

So you should execute your logic depending on whether Receiver is called after boot or due to Alarm. You can do something like this in your AlarmReceiver:

```
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("notify_message");
if(msg==null){
      //means that receiver started after boot
      // write your logic here
}else{
      //means that receiver started by alarm
      //write your logic here
}
```

Comment: So is there no way to store a specific value to retrieve after reboot? If you need to pass a user-defined value to survive reboot (without using sharedpreferences)  how would you possibly restore that value?